# HashSet not empty but cannot be iterated?

Tags: java, copy, hashset

I got this strange result when I tried to copy the elements of another list/set into a HashSet. Here's the code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
    HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();

    set1.add("A");
    set1.add("B");
    set1.add("C");

    Iterator<String> iter = set1.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        String elem = iter.next();
        set2.add(elem);      // copy the elements 
        System.out.println("set1: " + elem + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("SIZE = " + set2.size() + "; isEmpty = " + set2.isEmpty() + "; next = " + iter.hasNext());

    Iterator<String> iter2 = set2.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        String elem = iter2.next();
        System.out.println("set2: " + elem + " ");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
set1: A
set1: B 
set1: C 
SIZE = 3; isEmpty = false; next = false
```

As you can see, *set2* is not empty, but the iterator returns nothing while calling *next()*. I'm so confused. Could you explain this?

*Updates:

Thanks for all help! It's a stupid error...*

Comment: Typo: The last `while` loop uses the old `iter` variable instead of `iter2`.

Comment: The `iter` you are using is at the end, so there isn't any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop at the end is trying to iterate through iter & not iter2 (iterator for set2).
it should be

```
 while(iter2.hasNext())
 {
   ....
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it right after posting, stupid... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo - the second time you use `iter` again instead of `iter2`